# Which class in HIVE project does DML over MetaStore ? And which class picks MetaStore DB credentials?

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hive :- Create Table, AlterTable etc done needs some back end DML (MetaStore).
Which is the class that would do these ?
Which is the class that would fetch DB credentials from MetaStore ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetastoreClient which provides different methods to deal with the metastore in Hive